# Cordova Camera Plugin Slow & Flaky (works about 1/3 of the time) when called from iPhone app. (Error in orig Javascript code?)

Tags: javascript, ios, iphone, camera, cordova-plugins

Background: 
I have an ios app that is supposed to allow the user to take a photo from one of the screens.

The app was originally a website, written in html & javascript. Then Cordova converted it to an ios app written in Objective-C.

I added the cordova-plugin-camera plugin for camera functionality.

Problem:
The app works well, all except for the camera call.

****It only works around 1/3 of the time, and even then, it is after a delay of 5-6 seconds.****

When it doesn't work, nothing happens. The "take photo" button is just active for a moment, then not active.

Here's the original javascript:

```
var onDeviceReady;

onDeviceReady = function() {
  console.log(navigator.camera);
};

document.addEventListener('deviceready', onDeviceReady, false);

exports.takePicture = function(success, error) {
  if (!navigator.camera) {
    error();
    return;
  }
  console.log("About to take picture");
  return navigator.camera.getPicture(success, error, {
    quality: 80,
    destinationType: Camera.DestinationType.FILE_URI
  });
};

exports.hasCamera = function() {
  return navigator.camera != null;
};
```

So far, I've tested on iPhone 4s & 5c, & the problem exists on both of them.

I looked at other posts, but have not found a problem quite like this, or a solution that works for me.

Any help would be appreciated!! 
Thx!

Comment: Had you resolve this problem, I met this problem too, on ipad, use cordova camera plugin.